# Is this a new trend in using furigana?

Tags: discussion, furigana

In the highlighted text attached, the furigana are written after the word and not in brackets as usual. Is this a recent trend that is becoming popular or is it just that the particular site doesn't use certain HTML tags? Or something else maybe?

[image]

Comment: I think this could be asked as an orthography question on the main site, but I guess it can also stay here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this in printed dictionaries and don't think it's a recent trend at all.

It keeps the line spacing even (and tight) and thus saves space (important for dictionaries).

Comment: So it's a dictionary style spacing? Have you seen it in places other than dictionaries?

Comment: Usually a wider line (or column) spacing is easier to read, in which case it makes more sense to place *furigana* in this (dead) existing space, rather than creating new space. I've only seen it in dictionaries, where the line spacing is tight, but if you find another type of publication which requires tight line spacing, then this would be a good place to use it. I think in HTML, a text with *furigana* not on all lines will result in uneven line spacing, which is not ideal.

Comment: In dictionaries and other reference books with vertical text, these inline notes are typically split in half like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6PSw.jpg This splitting is called 割注 and I think it's also possible in horizontal text, but it's less common and I don't think I've seen it myself.

Comment: Wow, that 割注 is awesome, never seen that in the wild.